# WCF per-call service not timing out properly with an inactivityTimeout set to 1 minute

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a per-call service set to use a reliable session (transport session) however when I set the inactivity timeout to 1 minute the timeout does not work.
reliableSession enabled=true inactivityTimeout=00:01:00

When I set the receiveTimeout to 00:01:00 the client did timeout after one minute.

Why won't the inactivityTimeout fire when I don't explicitly set the receiveTimeout?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the time out on the client configuration remember there are timeouts for both sides.

Comment: The issue was  the receiveTimeout on the binding.
I learned that the inactivityTimeout for a reliableSession is only applicable if you have ordered set to true.

Now that the timeout is working properly with the receiveTimeout set, how can I tell when the timeout is fired?  On the client I am handling the faulted event which does in fact get fired when the timeout is fired but I can't find a way to tell if the channel is faulted due to a timeout or an exception being thrown by the service.